# How to navigate out of facebook app through web page?

Tags: java, android, html, facebook, facebook-apps

Is there a way to navigate to external browser in fb android app, like creating a web page when user navigate to it from facebook it open a web site "example.com" in chrome or another browser instead of fb in app browser.
please help with a code.

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: @WizKid, so how deep linking can be opened in another app?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks